# How to achieve fixed full height divs with scrollbar in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am building a page in bootstrap with three columns whose height should be 100% and with each having scrollbars and body not having a scrollbar. Like this
[image: my sample site]

So far my code is

```html
<main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
            Navigation Area <br />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            Content Area <br />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            Profile Area <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

I haven't added any extra css. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Remove body scrollbar

For removing scrollbar, use `overflow: hidden`

```css
body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

> Each col part have scrollbar

For add scrollbar, use `overflow: scroll`

```css
main div[class*="col-"] {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

> Achieve full height

For that you need to use `height: 100vh` and remove your navbar height from that, `Default` bootstrap navbar height is `116px` (with include padding).

```css
main {
    height: calc(100vh - 116px);
}
```

**Live Snippet for you**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
    body {
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    main div[class*="col-"] {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: 100vh;
    }
</style>

<main role="main" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ut reiciendis temporibus consequatur voluptatum adipisci velit modi expedita eaque, id perspiciatis facilis laudantium aliquam quam quo molestiae tempore est soluta.
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make position relative for `parent-main` and `absolute` for `child-settings` elements. Apply `overflow: auto;height:100%` to the child elements to overflow. And as nisharg mentioned you can remove the height of the navbar from the page by using `height: calc(100vh - "nav-height")`

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.settings {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="main">
          <div class="container settings" style="position: absolute;">
            <div class="box no-box-small-mobile">
              <div class="column">
                <h1>test</h1>
                <h1>test</h1>
                <h1>test</h1>
                <h1>test</h1>
                <h1>test</h1>
                <h1>test</h1>
                <h1>test</h1>
                <h1>test</h1>
                <h1>test</h1>
                <h1>test</h1>
                <h1>test</h1>
                <h1>test</h1>
                <h1>test</h1>
                <h1>test</h1>
                <h1>test</h1>
                <h1>test</h1>
                <h1>test</h1>
                <h1>test</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="main">
          <div class="container settings" style="position: absolute;">
            <div class="item">
              <div class="label">A thing</div>
              <div class="value">1.45</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="label">A thing</div>
              <div class="value">1.45</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="label">A thing</div>
              <div class="value">1.45</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="label">A thing</div>
              <div class="value">1.45</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="label">A thing</div>
              <div class="value">1.45</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="label">A thing</div>
              <div class="value">1.45</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="label">A thing</div>
              <div class="value">1.45</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="label">A thing</div>
              <div class="value">1.45</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="label">A thing</div>
              <div class="value">1.45</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="label">A thing</div>
              <div class="value">1.45</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="label">A thing</div>
              <div class="value">1.45</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="label">A thing</div>
              <div class="value">1.45</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="label">A thing</div>
              <div class="value">1.45</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="label">A thing</div>
              <div class="value">1.45</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="label">A thing</div>
              <div class="value">1.45</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="label">A thing</div>
              <div class="value">1.45</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="label">A thing</div>
              <div class="value">1.45</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="label">A thing</div>
              <div class="value">1.45</div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```